# 2006 Ford XLT Front Dash Vent Door plastic lever broken that was attached to the Mode Actuator (which works)

Tags: ford, hvac, explorer

2006 Ford Explorer XLT.  Got a loud snap sound with small piece bouncing around under dash on passenger side. Air flow changed to def and floor only. Searched online, pulled glove box, Front vent actuator door plastic lever broke pulled many dash parts, all the center dash area with radio and HVAC controls, the whole center console, lower panels on passenger side, but can't get to it! I can barley get a finger on it as it's to the right of the center dash area and up and to the left of the glove compartment area behind metal bracing. Please tell me how to get to this thing without pulling the whole dash or paying $1200.00 to the dealer for a 20-30$ self fix.... Help! If I can just get to it, I'm gonna use the (drill hole in plastic lever above the break, use wire tie between this hole and hole in the "working" actuator metal plunger shaft) method. Thanks so much!

Comment: There is more than one mode door actuator, need to know which one, driver, passenger mode door actuator? Is it on the front or rear of the AC heater box?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

If its the one I think it is.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the center console "face" vents door with the plastic control arm on its right side which connects to its own vaccum actuators metal shaft. Actuator works but the plastic arm of the vent door snapped off. When glove compartment is removed this actuator up behind the top left corner of the glove compartment opening and is behind a metal support/bracket. I've removed everything from the center console but can't get to it from that side either. Does that help? I've googled tons of sites but none are clear on how you get to this area to work on it. Seems that all show pictures of what it looks like and after the fix pictures, but none show actual removal or fixing in place. Thanks.